# Calculate quarter for dates given an example end date and quarter number

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, finance

I have an issue where I need to determine fiscal quarters, but won't always know the start/end dates for the quarters. They will, however, always be 3 months long. What I will know is the ending date of the current quarter, and what quarter and year that refers to. For example, I might be given:

Current Quarter: Q4
Current Year: 2021
Current Quarter End Date: 1/31/2021

How can I get the quarter for any other date? If any of those 3 values were to change, the query still needs to provide the quarter for any given date based on those 3 parameters.

I came up with the following, which puts the last 4 years into a temp table:

```
DECLARE @QuarterEnd             DATE            =   '1/31/2022'
,       @CurrentQuarter         INT             =   1
,       @CurrentYear            INT             =   2022
,       @Counter                INT             =   16
,       @qs                     INT             =   0
,       @qe                     INT             =   2
,       @DateToTest             DATE            =   '12/15/2021'

CREATE TABLE #Quarters (
        StartDate   DATE
,       EndDate     DATE
,       Qtr         INT
,       Yr          INT
)

WHILE @Counter <> 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Quarters VALUES (
            cast(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @QuarterEnd)-@qe , 0) as date)
        ,   cast(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @QuarterEnd)-@qs, -1) as date)
        ,   @CurrentQuarter
        ,   @CurrentYear
    )
    SET @Counter = @Counter - 1
    SET @qs = @qs + 3
    SET @qe = @qe + 3
    SET @CurrentQuarter = CASE WHEN @CurrentQuarter = 1 THEN 4 ELSE @CurrentQuarter - 1 END
    SET @CurrentYear = CASE WHEN @CurrentQuarter = 4 THEN @CurrentYear - 1 ELSE @CurrentYear END
END

SELECT  @DateToTest
,       (SELECT CONCAT('Q', Qtr, ' ', Yr) FROM #Quarters WHERE @DateToTest BETWEEN StartDate and EndDate)
FROM    #Quarters
```

However, this doesn't seem to be practical when I'm running queries that will return hundreds of thousands of records.

I suppose I can throw that into a function and call it with:

```
SELECT MyQuarter = dbo.MyQuarterFunction(@QuarterEnd, @CurrentQuarter, @CurrentYear, @DateToTest)
```

There has to be a more efficient way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: hi perhaps create a computed column, or a case statement that compares the date against constant values

Comment: `I won't always know the start/end dates for the quarters.` What do you mean? Does your company change their fiscal calendar often? If not (or you need to support multiple companies with different fiscal calendars), you can simply use [a calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/).

Comment: Users need to be able to run this same query for various clients, and not all clients have the same fiscal calendar. This query will eventually be used to populate a data table in SSRS, and I want to avoid maintaining a separate calendar table for each client with fiscal quarters if possible.

Comment: Are you actually going to have those three parameters stored in variables or do the actual values come from a column?

Comment: It's four rows per year you need to cover, this is not exactly a large, inefficient, or cumbersome dimension table if it eases support of your business logic. It's certainly a better place to store (and easier place to update) the rules for a specific business than a big function with a while loop and conditional logic.

Comment: The 3 parameters would come from parameters in an SSRS report, supplied by the user.

Comment: So the _user_ says "my quarter is Q4 and the current year is 2021 and the current quarter ends on 1/31/2021"? And this input is reliable? Wouldn't it be better for them to just pass their client id and a date or date range and the system figures it out for them? That's what a calendar table can do.

Comment: (And actually, I don't think the code in the question works the way you think it does - [it returns 16 identical rows](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d1a44e1376324c77f69de963d08c3e97).)

Comment: Imagine there are 10 users, and each user supports 10 different clients. The user knows each client's fiscal calendar (most have standard calendars, but there are enough exceptions to warrant this query). So when they go to run this report for Client A for Q2 2021, they know that quarter ended on 3/31/2021 (for example).

Comment: Right, but think about it: if the user knows the client's fiscal calendar, why not just store that? Then they only have to remember the client. I updated my answer to show this - all you need to store is the fiscal year for a client, now your users don't have to memorize any of the other details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have two input variables:

```
declare @quarter_end date = '2021-01-31';
declare @current_quarter int = 4;
```

You can calculate the first month of financial year:

```
declare @first_month_of_fy int = (month(@quarter_end) - @current_quarter * 3 + 12) % 12 + 1;
-- 2 i.e. February
```

And use that value to calculate the quarter and year for any date using some math:

```
select *
from (values
    ('2020-12-15'),
    ('2021-01-15'),
    ('2021-12-15'),
    ('2022-01-15')
) as t(testdate)
cross apply (select
    (month(testdate) - @first_month_of_fy + 12) % 12 + 1
) as ca1(month_of_fy)
cross apply (select
    (month_of_fy - 1) / 3 + 1,
    year(dateadd(month, 12 - month_of_fy, dateadd(day, - day(testdate) + 1, testdate)))
) as ca2(fy_quarter, fy_year)
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=19aea7ac5236ff46b30b44d12994602b)

Comment: This is very slick and does answer my question. I can slightly modify your code within my query to create a temp table with every date within the overall date range, and then join to that table on testdate = mydate. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just create a permanent table called `Quarters`.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Quarters
(
  StartDate     date,
  QuarterNumber tinyint,
  FiscalYear    int,
  NextQuarterStartDate AS (DATEADD(MONTH, 3, StartDate))
);

INSERT dbo.Quarters(StartDate, QuarterNumber, FiscalYear)
  VALUES('20200201',1,2020),
        ('20200501',2,2020),
        ('20200801',3,2020),
        ('20201101',4,2020),
        ('20210201',1,2021),
        ('20210501',2,2021),
        ('20210801',3,2021),
        ('20211101',4,2021),
        ('20220201',1,2022),
        ('20220501',2,2022),
        ('20220801',3,2022),
        ('20221101',4,2022);
```

Now any time you are given a date (like `GETDATE()`) you can find the other information easily:

```
DECLARE @date date = GETDATE();

SELECT * FROM dbo.Quarters 
  WHERE @date >= StartDate
  AND @date < NextQuarterStartDate;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0bedd4ef3ffa839b59857310da99812b)

If you need to support multiple fiscal calendars simultaneously, just add a column (like `CalendarID` or `CompanyID` or `CustomerID`).

And really, you don't even need a calendar or quarters table for this. You already have a table of clients, right? Just add a column to store what month their fiscal year starts. That's really all you need.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Clients
(
  ClientID        int           NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Clients PRIMARY KEY,
  Name            nvarchar(200) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT UQ_ClientName UNIQUE,
  FiscalYearStart tinyint       NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CK_ValidMonth 
    CHECK (FiscalYearStart BETWEEN 1 AND 12)
);
```

Now let's insert a few rows with some clients with different fiscal years:

```
INSERT dbo.Clients(ClientID, Name, FiscalYearStart)
  VALUES(1, N'ClientFeb',    2), -- fiscal year starts in February 
        (2, N'ClientMay',    5), -- fiscal year starts in May
        (3, N'ClientNormal', 1); -- fiscal year matches calendar
```

Now, yes, we need a function, but let's not do any while loops or counters or #temp tables.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetLast16Quarters
(
  @DateToTest date,
  @ClientID   int
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN 
(
  WITH n(n) AS
  (
    SELECT n = 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT n + 1 FROM n WHERE n < 20
  ),
  Last20Quarters(QuarterStart, FiscalYearStart) AS
  (
    SELECT QuarterStart = DATEADD(QUARTER, 1-n, 
      DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@DateToTest)+1, FiscalYearStart, 1)), 
      FiscalYearStart
    FROM dbo.Clients CROSS JOIN n WHERE ClientID = @ClientID
  ),
  Last16Quarters AS
  (
    SELECT TOP (16) QuarterStart, 
      y = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 1-FiscalYearStart, QuarterStart)) 
    FROM Last20Quarters WHERE QuarterStart < @DateToTest
    ORDER BY QuarterStart DESC
  )
  SELECT QuarterStart, 
         QuarterEnd = EOMONTH(QuarterStart, 2),
         FiscalYear = y,
         QuarterNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
           (PARTITION BY y ORDER BY QuarterStart)
  FROM Last16Quarters);
```

Then to call it:

```
DECLARE @DateToTest date = '20211215';
SELECT * FROM dbo.GetLast16Quarters(@DateToTest, 1);
```

Output:

> | QuarterStart | QuarterEnd | FiscalYear | QuarterNumber |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2018-02-01 | 2018-04-30 | 2018 | 1 |
> | 2018-05-01 | 2018-07-31 | 2018 | 2 |
> | 2018-08-01 | 2018-10-31 | 2018 | 3 |
> | 2018-11-01 | 2019-01-31 | 2018 | 4 |
> | 2019-02-01 | 2019-04-30 | 2019 | 1 |
> | 2019-05-01 | 2019-07-31 | 2019 | 2 |
> | 2019-08-01 | 2019-10-31 | 2019 | 3 |
> | 2019-11-01 | 2020-01-31 | 2019 | 4 |
> | 2020-02-01 | 2020-04-30 | 2020 | 1 |
> | 2020-05-01 | 2020-07-31 | 2020 | 2 |
> | 2020-08-01 | 2020-10-31 | 2020 | 3 |
> | 2020-11-01 | 2021-01-31 | 2020 | 4 |
> | 2021-02-01 | 2021-04-30 | 2021 | 1 |
> | 2021-05-01 | 2021-07-31 | 2021 | 2 |
> | 2021-08-01 | 2021-10-31 | 2021 | 3 |
> | 2021-11-01 | 2022-01-31 | 2021 | 4 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c6aff5bfc593bd5f09675cbcd3d008fa)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a function to handle this. Since I'm given the last day of the quarter, which quarter it is, and which year it is, I can determine the start and end date of that fiscal year. Since a quarter is always 3 months, I can also determine which months fall into which quarter.

The first 4 variables, @qa, @qb, @qc, @qd hold a comma separated list of the months within each quarter (@qa is current quarter, @qb is current quarter -1, @qc is current quarter -2, and @qd is current quarter -3)

The second 2 variables determine the first day and last day of the fiscal calendar

To get the quarter & year, I first get the month from the supplied date (@Date) and see if it's in @qa, @qb, @qc or @qd. That tells me the fiscal quarter.

Finally, I compare the given date to the start and end date of the current fiscal year, and to the 6 years prior (going back 6 years is enough for what I need)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FunctionNameHere]
(
    @Date           DATE
,   @QuarterEnd     DATE
,   @CurrentQuarter INT
,   @CurrentYear    INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(7)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE     @qa                 VARCHAR(8)  = (concat(datepart(m, dateadd(m,  0, @QuarterEnd)),',', datepart(m, dateadd(m, -1,  @QuarterEnd)),',', datepart(m, dateadd(m, -2,  @QuarterEnd))))
DECLARE     @qb                 VARCHAR(8)  = (concat(datepart(m, dateadd(m, -3, @QuarterEnd)),',', datepart(m, dateadd(m, -4,  @QuarterEnd)),',', datepart(m, dateadd(m, -5,  @QuarterEnd))))
DECLARE     @qc                 VARCHAR(8)  = (concat(datepart(m, dateadd(m, -6, @QuarterEnd)),',', datepart(m, dateadd(m, -7,  @QuarterEnd)),',', datepart(m, dateadd(m, -8,  @QuarterEnd))))
DECLARE     @qd                 VARCHAR(8)  = (concat(datepart(m, dateadd(m, -9, @QuarterEnd)),',', datepart(m, dateadd(m, -10, @QuarterEnd)),',', datepart(m, dateadd(m, -11, @QuarterEnd))))
DECLARE     @YearStart          DATE        = DATEADD(d, 1, DATEADD(q, -@CurrentQuarter, @QuarterEnd))
DECLARE     @YearEnd            DATE        = DATEADD(q, 4-@CurrentQuarter, @QuarterEnd)

DECLARE     @Qtr                VARCHAR(8)  =   CONCAT('Q', CASE WHEN DATEPART(m, @Date) IN (SELECT value FROM string_split(@qa, ',')) THEN @CurrentQuarter 

                                                                 WHEN DATEPART(m, @Date) IN (SELECT value FROM string_split(@qb, ',')) THEN CASE WHEN @CurrentQuarter = 1 THEN 4
                                                                                                                                                 WHEN @CurrentQuarter = 2 THEN 1
                                                                                                                                                 WHEN @CurrentQuarter = 3 THEN 2
                                                                                                                                                 WHEN @CurrentQuarter = 4 THEN 3 END

                                                                 WHEN DATEPART(m, @Date) IN (SELECT value FROM string_split(@qc, ',')) THEN CASE WHEN @CurrentQuarter = 1 THEN 3
                                                                                                                                                 WHEN @CurrentQuarter = 2 THEN 4
                                                                                                                                                 WHEN @CurrentQuarter = 3 THEN 1
                                                                                                                                                 WHEN @CurrentQuarter = 4 THEN 2 END

                                                                 WHEN DATEPART(m, @Date) IN (SELECT value FROM string_split(@qd, ',')) THEN CASE WHEN @CurrentQuarter = 1 THEN 2
                                                                                                                                                 WHEN @CurrentQuarter = 2 THEN 3
                                                                                                                                                 WHEN @CurrentQuarter = 3 THEN 4
                                                                                                                                                 WHEN @CurrentQuarter = 4 THEN 1 END
                                                END,
                                                ' ',
                                                CASE WHEN @Date BETWEEN @YearStart AND @YearEnd THEN @CurrentYear
                                                     WHEN @Date BETWEEN dateadd(Year, -1, @YearStart) AND dateadd(Year, -1, @YearEnd) THEN @CurrentYear - 1
                                                     WHEN @Date BETWEEN dateadd(Year, -2, @YearStart) AND dateadd(Year, -2, @YearEnd) THEN @CurrentYear - 2
                                                     WHEN @Date BETWEEN dateadd(Year, -3, @YearStart) AND dateadd(Year, -3, @YearEnd) THEN @CurrentYear - 3
                                                     WHEN @Date BETWEEN dateadd(Year, -4, @YearStart) AND dateadd(Year, -4, @YearEnd) THEN @CurrentYear - 4
                                                     WHEN @Date BETWEEN dateadd(Year, -5, @YearStart) AND dateadd(Year, -5, @YearEnd) THEN @CurrentYear - 5
                                                     WHEN @Date BETWEEN dateadd(Year, -6, @YearStart) AND dateadd(Year, -6, @YearEnd) THEN @CurrentYear - 6
                                                     ELSE 9999 END)

    return @Qtr

END
```